# codeigniter ajax return whole html code instead of given div part

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

Here is my ajax code:

```
function choosecab(thisvalue){
    var carname =$(thisvalue).data('carname');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url+"welcome/getcab",                         
        data: "carname="+carname, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){    
                    console.log(html);          
                $(".right-side-widget").html(html);
                //window.location.href= base_url+"Tariff";  
        }
    });


}
```

Here is my controller:

```
if($_POST):
        if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)):
            $data = $_POST;             
            $cabfilter=array(
                "carchoosed" =>  $data['carname'],
                "page" => "Tariff/cabfilter",
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata('form2data', $cabfilter);
        $this->load->view('tariff', $cabfilter);    
        endif;
    endif;
```

cabfilter view contains the following code,

```
             <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 inp-align" >
                <div class="row sel-car-row" style="padding:0;">
                   <div class="col-lg-12">
                      <select name="car_id" class="selectpicker tariff-select-picker" required="" data-style="btn-info">
                         <option selected="selected" disabled >Select Members </option>     
                         <option  >2 </option>          
                         <option >4 </option>                                                                                    
                         <option  >6 </option>          
                      </select> 
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
```

The response from the ajax call includes the header and footer content. Here I need only the div part which is loaded by the controller.I can't guess what's wrong with the code?Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: show your full `tariff.php` view file

Comment: tariff.php is just for testing.I need to show the  cabfilter.php view which has the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$this->load->view('tariff', $cabfilter);
```

to

```
echo $this->load->view('cabfilter', $cabfilter, TRUE);
```